# How can I disable a “view cart” btn until after a product is added to the cart?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-hook

I have added a function that adds a “view cart” button next to the “add to cart” button. I would like the button to be disabled (either not showing or greyed out) **until someone adds the product to the cart**.

Here is my function:

```
    function action_woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button() {

    echo '<div class="woocommerce-message krank-mesg" role="alert"><a 
    href="./cart/" class="button wc-forward">VIEW CART</a> <p 
    class"woo-fx-added"><span>The New Formula X Driver</span> has 
    been added to your cart.</p></div>';

    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 
    'action_woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 10, 0 );
```

Here is the page:
http://krankfinance.wpengine.com/#product

I would like my view cart button on the above page to function like the view cart button (after the product is added to cart) on this page:
http://krankfinance.wpengine.com/shop/easy-pay-formula-x-driver/

Been working on this for 5 hours, googling anything I can but I can't seem to find an answer. Didn't think it would be this hard :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

> *Accepted solution above in PHP, my answer is also work (pure JS/CSS)*

You have a span object with the classname `cart-items` - u can use it to detect wether you have a product in your cart.

First make the **View-Cart button** hidden through CSS.

Then try with JS something like this:

```
if(parseInt($('.cart-items').html()) > 0) {
 $('.krank-mesgs').show();
}
```

### UPDATE

Cause your site is put content with a js-function, you need to detect changes and then fire actions like this:

Javascript (jQuery):

```
$("body").on('DOMSubtreeModified', ".cart-items", function() {
  if(parseInt($('.cart-items').html()) > 0) {
   $('.krank-mesgs').show();
  }
});
```

CSS :

```
.krank-mesgs {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but where do I add the class 'cart-items' ?

Comment: cart-items is already a existing object in your html-code, thats the badge on cart-icon @ site-header - You need just to use it, you use wordpress you can install a plugin "custom css/js"

Comment: Hi, It's not working. I added your code to the head above the body exactly like this:  ---- 
`<script type="text/javascript">
   if(parseInt($('.cart-items').html()) > 0) {
   $('.krank-mesg').show();
} 
</script>`  ---- 

      And I tried this:  ---- 


`<script>
   if(parseInt($('.cart-items').html()) > 0) {
   $('.krank-mesg').show();
 } 
</script>`

  ---- and I used this CSS to hide the button:  ----      
`.krank-mesg {visibility: hidden;}`

  ---- The button is hidden but it doesn't show when adding product to cart.

Comment: Hey, thats cause the cart-item is loaded by an other javascript function. You need to detect it, here I wrote a fiddle for you https://jsfiddle.net/8h7opwje/ , and look at css section you need to write display: none; (I edit Answer above)

Comment: Hi and thanks again!
I got it to work using this function

Comment: function action_woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button() {
    // Check if the cart isn't empty.
    if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
        echo '<div class="woocommerce-message krank-mesg" role="alert"><a href="./cart/" class="button wc-forward">VIEW CART</a> <p class"woo-fx-added"><span>The New Formula X Driver</span> has been added to your cart.</p></div>';
    } else {
      }
};
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'action_woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 10, 0 );

Comment: Your solution is without javascript, nice to hear its working. Good Luck

Comment: This is my first time on stackoverflow. Should I have added a different tag to my question?

Comment: The tags are ok

Answer (score 2):

Here is what worked for me.

```
    function action_woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button() {
// Check if the cart isn't empty.
if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
    echo '<div class="woocommerce-message krank-mesg" role="alert"><a href="./cart/" class="button wc-forward">VIEW CART</a> <p class"woo-fx-added"><span>The New Formula X Driver</span> has been added to your cart.</p></div>';
} else {
  }
    };
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 
    'action_woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 10, 0 );
```

Thanks for your help